# c++ BITMAPINFOHEADER biBitCount equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, c++, image-processing

everybody i am trying to convert a c++ code to c# .
this code that is compressing the bitmap image. my c++ code uses BITMAPINFOHEADER
to read biBitCount of a bitmap image , how can i get bit count of an image in c# (win app) ?.
this is the c++ code

```
char *pTemp; //image data will store here
BITMAPINFOHEADER *pbminfo;
pbminfo = (BITMAPINFOHEADER *)pTemp;
if ( pbminfo->biBitCount != 1 ) // Convert 24 bit -> 1 bit 
{
     //some process will be done here
}
```

Comment: The rewrite will be substantial.  Don't throw away code that works, write a managed class wrapper for your C++ code using the C++/CLI language.

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed write a wrapper class in Visual C++/CLI, but everything you'd want to do is perfectly doable using just C# on your end.

You can use the [`PixelFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.pixelformat%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of an Image. It has a wide variety of [possible values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> The pixel format defines the number of bits of memory associated with one pixel of data. The format also defines the order of the color components within a single pixel of data.
>
> PixelFormat48bppRGB, PixelFormat64bppARGB, and PixelFormat64bppPARGB use 16 bits per color component (channel). GDI+ version 1.0 and 1.1 can read 16-bits-per-channel images, but such images are converted to an 8-bits-per-channel format for processing, displaying, and saving. Each 16-bit color channel can hold a value in the range 0 through 2^13.
>
> Some of the pixel formats contain premultiplied color values. Premultiplied means that the color values have already been multiplied by an alpha value.

```
var image = new Bitmap(@"C:\temp\me.png");
if (image != null) {
    Console.Write("Format: {0}", image.PixelFormat.ToString("G"));
}
```

The result in my case will be: `Format32bppArgb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
using System.Drawing;

public class TestThis
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Image myImage = Image.FromFile("Myfile.png");

        int bitDepth = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(myImage.PixelFormat);

        if( bitDepth != 1)
        {
            // Do domething
        }
    }
}
```